# Apache Ignite on DCOS marathon not working

Tags: ignite

I installed Apache ignite in DCOS

```
{
   "volumes": null,
  "id": "/ignite",
   "cmd": "cd $MESOS_SANDBOX; java -Xmx2048m -jar ignite-mesos-2.0.0.jar",
  "args": null,
  "user": null,
  "env": {
    "IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE": "3072",
    "IGNITE_NODE_COUNT": "3",
    "IGNITE_VERSION": "2.0.0",
    "MESOS_MASTER_URL": "zk://localhost:2181/mesos",
    "IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE": "0.1"
  },
  "cpus": 1,
  "mem": 3072.0,
  "instances": 1,
  "uris": ["http://servername/ignite/ignite-mesos-2.0.0.jar"],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "openjdk:8-alpine",
      "network": "HOST",
      "portMappings": [
        { "containerPort": 0, "hostPort": 0, "servicePort": 0, "protocol": "tcp" }
      ]
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "DCOS_SERVICE_SCHEME": "http",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_NAME": "ignite",
    "DCOS_SERVICE_PORT_INDEX": "0"
  },
  "acceptedResourceRoles": ["*","slave_public"]
}
```

i get the below error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mesos in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)

i tried keeping  "MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY": "/usr/lib/libmesos.so", but still same error

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly add that .so to java.library.path and keep env variable "MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY" configured.

Also, start job-server with root privileges.